# KO3 - Kohana 3 - How can I pass $_POST data from a controller/action back to the view/form that called it?

Tags: validation, forms, view, controller, kohana-3

I am trying to validate a form submission in Kohana 3.  I have the form::open point to my action_create in my controller which successfully validates the data posted to it from the form in my view.  If the data passes validation, a new item is created as intended, and the user is redirected to the item that was just created.  This works correctly.  If the data fails validation, however, I would like the user to be directed back to the originating view/page while retaining a variable containing the data that was posted so that I can repopulate the form and display errors.

In short, how can I pass data from a view -> controller -> original view?

Thank you, everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user also posed [this question on the Kohana forums](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/comments.php?DiscussionID=6416).
Those seeking an answer to this should have look over there.

Comment: That link is broken. Too bad the gist of it wasn't included in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Controller_Template.

File **views/form.php**:

```
// Set default variables if variables not passed to this view
$username = isset($username) ? $username : '';

echo Form::open('login');

// Input: username
echo Form::label('username', 'Username');
echo Form::input('username', $username);
echo isset($errors['username']) ? $errors['username'] : '';

// Input: username
echo Form::label('password', 'Password');
echo Form::input('password', $password);
echo isset($errors['password']) ? $errors['password'] : '';

echo Form::close();
```

File **views/template.php**

```
<html>
    <head><title>My Website</title></head>

    <body>
        <?php echo isset($content) ? $content : ''; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

File **classes/controller/user.php**

```
Class Controller_User extends Controller_Template {

    public $template = 'template';

    public function index() 
    {

        $this->template->content = $this->display_form('form');

    }

    public function login() 
    {

        // Setup validation & rules here



        // Check validation, assume $validation is Validation object
        if ($validation->check()
        {
             // Validation succeeded. Do anything you want here


        }
        else
        {
             // Validation failed. Display form with entered values

             $form_vars = $_POST;
             $form_vars['errors'] = $validation->errors();

             // Display form
             $this->template->content = $this->display_form('form', $form_vars);

        }

    }

    // Displaying form
    private function display_form($form_file, $form_vars=NULL)
    {

        $form = View::factory($form_file);

        if ($form_vars != NULL)
        {

            foreach($form_vars as $key => $value)
            {
                $form->$key = $value;
            }

        }

        return $form;

    }

}
```

Hope that helps!